# I have a problem with Locking the Cursor (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code locks the cursor only when I left click my mouse after pressing Escape Key. Can anyone suggest me a way to overcome this problem?

```
public class lockCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool locked = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {

            if (locked == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("locked");
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                locked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Unlocked");
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                locked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired behavior?

Comment: It looks like it locks when you just press Esc without clicking if the app is in focus.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, I want to achieve this, but currently, it only locks when I left click on the screen.

Comment: @derHugo I want to lock the cursor when I press Escape, but currently, I have to click on the screen after pressing Escape to lock it.

Comment: You mean you press ESC, you see the message and only after clicking your cursor is actually locked? Or do you rather mean the debug log isn't shown at all when pressing ESC until you once clicked into the GameView (which btw is by design and the expected behavior since it allows you to e.g. change some Inspector values without this keyboard input also handled by the GameView)?

Comment: @derHugo The message is shown but the cursor is only locked after clicking on the screen.

Comment: Might be related to `In the Editor the cursor is automatically reset when escape is pressed, or on switching applications.` ?

Comment: @derHugo Can you rephrase I did not understand what you mean?

Comment: It's from the API for [`Cursor.lockState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html) and might mean that what happens is that you set the lockstate but due to the ESC button having a special role within the Editor it maybe resets the lockstate immediately so you it doesn't behave as you expect?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, Thank You. Changing the key solved the problem, but  I want to keep it to Escape key. Can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Hm well you could probably use a different KeyCode just for the editor and use escape in a build .. beyond that it gets probably tricky since you somehow would need to intercept the key press before Unity it handles itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the API for [`Cursor.lockState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html)

> In the Editor the cursor is automatically reset when **escape** is pressed, or on switching applications.

Due to escape having a special role itself within the Unity Editor the GameView loses focus when pressing it.

There is not really a (trivial) way around this since it would require to intercept they keypress before the Unity Editor itself gets the chance to handle that escape press. (Which would always happen before it is passed on to the player -> your code.)

---

What you **can** do however would be simply use a different KeyCode only for the editor and escape only in a build like e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
#else
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
#endif
    {
        ...
```

You can replace the `E` with any other KeyCode you wish to use to "simulate the escape key" only within the Unity Editor itself. (Also see [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html))

Answer (score 2):

As derHugo mentioned in his comment, your issue lies in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html) for `Cursor.lockState` where it says:

> "In the Editor the cursor is automatically reset when `escape` is
>   pressed, or on switching applications. In the Standalone Player you
>   have full control over the mouse cursor, but switching applications
>   still resets the cursor."

When you go to press `Escape`, it removes you from the application/Game Window. This is why it'll appear like your cursor is no longer locked. This is also why it goes into it's locked state as soon as you click back into the game. The same thing can be demonstrated by using your code, starting the game and then switching into another window on another monitor. Then move your mouse back over to the screen where the Game Window is. It'll appear as though it is no longer in a locked state... that is until you click in the game and it recognizes the cursor again.

To solve your problem, I would recommend using any key other than `KeyCode.Escape`. Maybe `KeyCode.Space` like the API shows.

Also, to further demonstrate the issue here, once you switch the code to use `KeyCode.Space`, press `Space` to lock the cursor and then try pressing `Escape`. Again you'll see that it appears to be unlocked until you press the `Left Mouse Button` in the Game Window again. This is because the Game thinks that you are no longer in the Game Window once you press `Escape`.

Hope this helps!